# Program for class to class type conversion using conversion constructor crashed

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion, destructor

In the code below I am trying to convert `int *` type to `vector` class. But upon running the program, program terminates after a halt in the conversion constructor to copy values from `int[]` into `vector::int *v`.

Also, this is an example from one of the books. I have been trying to figure out what is happening here. Any leads would be helpful.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

const int size=3;

template <class T>
class vector{
    T*v;
    public:
        vector()
        {
            v=new T[size];
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
                cout << "A" << endl;
                v[i]=0;
            }
            cout << "vector 0-arg ctor" << endl;
        }
        vector(T *a) ///////////////////// conversion ctor for type conversion
        {
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
                cout << "B" << endl; 

                v[i]=a[i];////////////////// Program exits here 

            }
            cout << "vector 1-arg ctor" << endl;
        }
        T operator*(vector &y)
        {
            T sum=0;
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
                cout << "C" << endl;
                sum += this->v[i] * y.v[i];
            }
            return sum;
        }
};

int main(){
    int x[3]={1,2,3};
    int y[3]={4,5,6};
    vector <int> v1;
    vector <int> v2;

    v1=x; ////////////////////// Type conversion from int * -> vector
    v2=y; ////////////////////// int * -> vector

    int R=v1*v2;
    cout << "R : " << R << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is below ->

```
A
A
A
vector 0-arg ctor
A
A
A
vector 0-arg ctor
B
```

Comment: This question is also a very fun example of [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). C++17 added `std::size` and, well, I'll let Mr. Godbolt demonstrate: https://godbolt.org/z/PyeWmk

Comment: @user4581301 I removed the namespace and made changes,https://godbolt.org/z/VhrECE. But the output remains the same.

Comment: Your rubber duck wants to know what `v` is pointing at in `vector(T *a)`.

Comment: Good complete question, by the way.

Comment: @user4581301, But in the 0-arg ctor, the compiler knows what 'v' is pointing to. Hence, I think the compiler must be knowing what 'v' is pointing to.

Comment: For a given instantiation of a class, only one class constructor gets selected to be called.

Comment: A constructor makes a brand new instance, so setting `v1`'s `v` has no bearing on the anonymous `vector`'s `v`. Also watch out for the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). It will strike next because you lack an assignment operator.

Comment: @user4581301, I studied about Rule of three. But how to make 1-arg ctor know the instance v1 as mentioned in your 1st point.

Comment: @give_it_a_bit I think that explains the whole problem. Let me know if and where it doesn't and I'll expand. But it'll be a couple hours before I get back to a computer.

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, thanks for the elaborate answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At

```
v1=x;
```

Two things happen:

1. A brand new temporary `vector` is constructed using `vector(T *a)`. This temporary `vector` is in no way associated with `v1`
2. The temporary `vector` is assigned to `v1` using a compiler-generated default assignment operator.

Unfortunately, `vector(T *a)` does not allocate for `v` or assign existing storage to `v`. Since `v` does not point at a valid object, dereferencing it invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and could do anything. On the asker's computer, it looks as though `v[i]=a[i];` writes into invalid memory and causes a crash. Would that we were all so lucky.

## Solution

Allocate some storage for `v`

```
vector(T *a): v(new T[size])
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        cout << "B" << endl; 
         v[i]=a[i];
    }
    cout << "vector 1-arg ctor" << endl;
}
```

I used a [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) as an example. It's tragically under-taught and amazingly useful.

Do not try

```
vector(T *a): v(a)
{
}
```

even though it looks very tempting. There is no way for the the `vector` destructor that will need to be written sometime in the near future to prevent memory leaks to be able to tell the statically allocated array `x`, which cannot be `delete`ed without invoking Undefined Behaviour, from the dynamic allocation provided by default constructor, which must be `delete`ed.

And since the topic of destructors have come up, it is important to be aware of the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Step 2 of `v1=x;` performs an assignment. The compiler-generated default assignment operator is very simple and very stupid. It copies exactly what is in one `vector` to another. If it sees a pointer, it copies the address, not what's pointed at. Whatever was pointed at by the destination object there is not `delete`ed and is probably lost. This leaves you with two objects pointing to the same memory. Changing one object can now change the other and chaos ensues.

After this assignment `v1`'s `v` will have been replaced by the temporary `vector`'s, leaking `v1`'s original memory allocation. Worse, the temporary `vector` lives up to the name and promptly goes out of scope. As soon as `vector` has a functioning destructor, the temporary will take its `v` with it, and since `v1` and the temporary are now pointed at the same memory allocation, `v1`'s `v` is left pointing at invalid memory.

An assignment operator is required to clean this mess up. See the [Copy and Swap Idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) for a very simple, very safe way to write an assignment operator.

Comment: Using the code in step-1 and implementing own copy assignment operator, as mentioned in step-2 solved the problem.